# how to add progress bar to zip utility while zipping or extracting in java?

Tags: java, swing, zip, progress-bar, unzip

I would like to show progress bar in my swing app, which will zip the selected file.
for this process i want to show a progress bar while processing.It may be in a JOptionPane or a given panel as a parameter to utility.

```
//Select a text file to be zip    
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));


chooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File f) {
    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
        || f.isDirectory();
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return "GIF Images";
  }
});

String source ="";
int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   source = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
  File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

//Start ZIP
try {

        String target = "upload/data-1.zip";
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        // put a new ZipEntry in the ZipOutputStream
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));

        int size = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
        pb.setStringPainted(true);
        pb.setIndeterminate(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(pb);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(panel);



        // read data to the end of the source file and write it to the zip
        // output stream.
        while ((size = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, size);
               pb.setValue(size);
               pb.repaint();
               if (size >= file.size) {
                 panel.dispose();
               }
            <<HERE I TRIED TO GIVE PROGRESS ABR VALUE BUT NOT SUCCEDED>>
        }

        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();

        // Finish zip process
        zos.close();
        System.out.println("finished");
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: what is the question? The given code doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). You can update UI with intermediate results using `process()` method. Also, `SwingWorker` has bound `progress` property. You can use [setProgress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) to update it. Then, add `PropertyChangeListener` to respond to `progress` property updates.

Check out [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). The article demonstrates collaboration of SwingWorker with a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

you can't zip the file on the EventDispatchThread, or your Gui is blocked during the process and you won't see progress in the ProgressBar. Use a SwingWorker.